# Brownian Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

In one of the question on forum $Pr (Z(1) < 0, Z(2) < 0)$ is calculated. I have a slightly similar question $Pr ( Z(1) < 0, Z(2) < 0, Z(3) < 0)$ ?

$Z(1), Z(2) \; and \; Z(3)$ are brownian motion points at $t=1,2,3$

Is there a formula simpler than the one involving integrals of Gaussian distributions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is
$$p:=P(Z_1<0,Z_2<0)=P(Z_1<0,Z_2-Z_1<-Z_1)$$
But $Z_2-Z_1$ is independent of $Z_1$ so eventually we are just computing
$$p=P(X<0,X+Y<0)$$
where $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Now you can see this as an integral w.r.t. the bivariate Gaussian density of course. Or you can just say that it all boils down to cutting a piece of cake. If the bivariate density is a cake then the value $p$ is a $3/8$ slice (the two lines delimitates $3/8$ of the plane). Exact same reasoning in higher dimension.
$$p=P(X<0,X+Y<0,X+Y+Z<0)$$
Imagine a unit sphere in 3d and cut it according to the 3 lines.

Comment: Maybe I am too uninitiated in Brownian, I can visualize the Bivariate Gaussian density though I am unable to see how the piece 3/8 can be obtained. 
I mean is there a more intuitive way to visualize this? (I am able to calculate 3/8 but not for trivariate case...)

Comment: You are computing a surface over R^2, the density is not changed by rotating around the z-axis and you are slicing R^2 by passing through 0. It is equivalent to slicing a disk centered in 0 in the plane and finding the ratio between the remaining area after slicing and the disk area.

Comment: Two thumbs up for the sphere cutting intuition vanna.!